# Move JavaScript to an external file when it has document.getElementById('<%= control.ClientID%>') in it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, refactoring

I have an existing ASP.NET web page with a few hundred lines of JavaScript code inline on the page.

The code is full of code that references server-side control names, such as this:

```
  function SetVisibility(isVisible) {
    document.getElementById('<%=someDiv.ClientID%>').style.display = (isVisible ? "block" : "none");
  }
```

If I move the script to an external .JS file, the .ClientID references are no longer resolved, and the page collapses in a pile of errors.

What is the best way to solve this problem?  I can change every function to take controls as arguments, or I can replace the .getElementByID with $find()... but I'm hoping there is an easier/faster way.

Comment: Try to move all variable assignments to a page to a js variable, and use that variable in these functions. if you are at  v4.0 you can use clientID static mode as well so you don't have to do the previous step. Reason being js files are not rendered by asp.net engine so these never gets resolved. If you are using plugins like jquery then you could easily do a binding to className assigning cssClass to your controls or even to Id contains something (eg: id contains someDiv).

Comment: How about `<script src="foo.aspx"></script>` ..or anything ASP.Net engine handles (cshtml, ashx, vbhtml)?

Comment: Check out this as well http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2007/09/Creating-JavaScript-objects-from-ASPNET-objects

Comment: @PSL, I think i explained with some code. Does this help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move the inline ASP.NET syntax like `<%= or <#` to your external javascript files.

All you need is, you should have a proper reference to the element id.

**Case 1:**

> ID is auto generated by ASP.Net runtime and no ClientIDMode
>   available(ASP.Net < 4.0)

***Solution***:

In a .aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myHtmlElementIDs={};
myHtmlElementIDs.ContainerDiv='<%=someDiv.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

In JS File

```
function SetVisibility(isVisible) {
    document.getElementById(myHtmlElementIDs.ContainerDiv).style.display 
     = (isVisible ? "block" : "none");
  }
```

**Case 2:**

> Control on Generating Client ID. No Master page or nested control is
>   used, or `ClientIDMode=Static` is available(ASP.Net >= 4.0)

***Solution***: No need to worry about ClientID, since it will not be changed

```
function SetVisibility(isVisible) {
    document.getElementById('actualControlID').style.display 
     = (isVisible ? "block" : "none");
  }
```

Comment: This is great, thank you.  Is there any downside to setting the ClientIDMode to static?

Comment: @JosephStyons, There is no downside. We all were struggle with this issue and ASP.Net team introduced this in 4.0 to solve this. Happy Coding!!!